We're now "Okay" on the Area 51 Avid Users Statistic: August 2012
I just noticed that we've just switched from "needs work" to "okay" on the avid user count on Area 51. There's still much to do to get this site to where it's really thriving, but it's nice to pass another milestone.

To turn this vaguely into a question:

Are there any other strategies we could adopt to improve our site statistics?


I would like to be the first one to say: \o/

Are there any other strategies we could adopt to improve our site statistics? Yes, it would be very helpful if users start (or continue) to upvote good, quality content on a consistent basis.  http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/266/vote-early-vote-often

It seems like, to a first approximation, that just a handful of us voting on a consistent basis, and really, everyone should have a say in the process.  I'm with Josh and Jeromy, I think this is fantastic, but we can do even better!!

Meta posts don't have to be a question :P

@ChuckSherrington yeah, agreed; I'd like to see a lot more voting going on than currently happens. Hopefully expanding the avid user base means there will be more though.

I will parrot Ben and jonsca, we need more voting and self-moderation (VtC, commenting, editing, etc) happening from some of the newer avid users. I am definitely excited that our user base is steadily growing! Hopefully we will get a big bump in September.
